# Подключение к wifi через netsh c#

Tags: c#, windows-10, netsh

Как можно вывести список сетей, уровень их сигнала, и подключиться к сети через netsh c#?

Answer (score 1):

```
string arguments = "interface ip set address \"Local Area Connection\" static 192.168.106.181 255.255.255.0";
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", arguments);

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process.Start(procStartInfo);
```

Взято [отсюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fd3d708-d54f-4411-9097-3d91e44ba23b/how-to-use-netsh-command-in-c-application-for-windows-7-machine?forum=csharpgeneral).

Вот [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495297/c-sharp-to-run-cmd-netsh) на enSO.
Документация - [Using Netsh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490939(v=technet.10))
Команды для работы с  WiFi - https://superuser.com/a/991484/750112

Comment: к wifi. Список wifi сетей. Уровень сигнала wifi. Подключиться к сети WIFI!